# How to load values from table columns which are not mapped on the corresponding entity framework type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Assume having a table named `Info`, which is not completly mapped to its entity framework (EF) type. It has Id column which is visible on the EF type and N other nvarchar columns, which are not accessible, i.e. mapped on EF type. For example:

*DB table:*

```
Id INT, column1 NVARCHAR, column2 NVARCHAR, ..., columnN  NVARCHAR
```

*EF type and context:*

```
public class Info
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("name=myDbContext") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Info> Infos { get; set; }
}
```

**Question 1:**

Is there a way to access not mapped columns on the loaded EF entity? Are they even loaded? For example, I want to retrieve values of `column1..columnN` from `new MyDbContext().Infos.First()`?

**Question 2:**

My assumption is that the answer to the first question is no, so here is the followup question:

By using EF, what would be the best way to retrieve the values of all nvarchar columns (in this case column1..columnN) without knowing how many columns in fact exist? In another words, how can I query the `Info` table by Id and get all nvarchar columns in `Dictionary<string, string> dictionary`, in order to access values as `dictionary["column1"]`? Assume I query it by Id and thus expect single result, i.e. single dictionary.

Comment: I would say that answer to both questions is somewhere between "not possible" and "hardly possible". I suggest breaking a table into several ones, 1 for Info, others for your column1..N metadata and load data this way. Can you afford it?

Comment: @raderick: columns 1..n are not metadata columns. They contain data. Why would splitting help me? I still need to load that data somehow. It would just complicate the the situation even more.

Comment: then you pretty much have to provide a complete and valid configuration for Entity Framework. It also looks like switching to some key-value or another non-relational DB will help you, if you really want it to be that dynamic.

Comment: Key/value is not possible, because of the necessity for querieying with simple selects. I do not see how would key/value help to solve the posted problem? I do not need redesign. I simply need to find a way to load values of columns, other than those mapped on EF object in key/value representation, without knowing how many of such columns exist.

Answer (score 1):

The database context object has a Database property which is essentially the database connection. You can run straight SQL queries via this object. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) shows examples.

However, you can't get the columns into a EF object: after all, you have excluded them from the Model so they don't exist as per your instructions. You can still create your own objects to hold them, though.

Comment: The page you are citing, does not provide solution to my problem. I do not always  know what columns my table has, and thus cannot create the class to load them by Database.SqlQuery.